# Unable to insert into table with column names as from , to

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

A table has columns like `from` and `to`, and when I am trying to insert into table using Spring Data REST and Spring Data JPA `JpaRepository`, I am getting error as below:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tbl_user_location
        (city, description, 
    from
        ,            
        to,
        user_id) 
    values
        (?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?)
```

> 11:57:49,485 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():146 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from' at line 1

Once I removed those 2 columns, it inserted successfully with status 201 created with headers application/json.

---

Library versions:

- Spring Data JPA- 1.8.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
- Spring Data Rest Repository - 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is not recommended to use keywords as column names, obviously for these reasons.

To solve your problem you have to refer to such columns with the names in square brackets, e.g. `[from]` and `[to]`.

Comment: Daniel I am reverse engineering a database and there these tables preexist. I am also not writign INSERT myself, it is Spring Data JPA and Spring Data REST which is generating a REST URL to which I am posting this data. Any chance changing @Column annotation in entity  to [from] ?

Comment: Annotating as @Column(name = "[to]") solved this issue, in insert statement generated there is `to` inside back quotes

Comment: @fortm I understand that modifying the table is not an option in this case, still I thought it is worth pointing out that to avoid such annoyances it is better practice to not to create tables that way in the first place.